# VBA default value for multiple combo boxes

Tags: vba, combobox

I would like to ask you to help me set up default value for multiple comboboxes. I used code below, but it will change only default value of first combobox. When I close it and open 2nd time, 2nd value will be changed to default, 3rd time, 3 value and so on. 
I need to change all default values of all my comboboxes in userform within initialization.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    CBForm.ListIndex = 0
    CBERP.ListIndex = 0
    CBCountry.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any `Change` events linked to your comboboxes?  E.g. Do you have a `CBForm_Change` that will be fired when you set `CBForm.ListIndex = 0`?  If so, what does the code do?

Comment: I tested it and I found out, that it is caused by ControlSource value. I set up there cell where should be value written. If it is empty it works, so I think I will put into code where will be value written instead of setting it directly in combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's not working... but try the next.
Create a procedure in your `UserForm` code to set the initial values:

```
Private Sub InitializeCombos()
    CBForm.ListIndex = 0
    CBERP.ListIndex = 0
    CBCountry.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Then, call your procedure at `UserForm_Initialize`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call InitializeCombos
End Sub
```

Comment: It didn't work as well. It works if I am stepping process, but as soon as I am trying to run it, it will change only default value for first combobox.

Comment: Try @YowE3K suggestion. Something is wrong with your user form.
You can try this code in a new UserForm and it should works.